# Can't find memory leaks in c

Tags: c, memory

I run createNewBoard which calls createNewMatrix and the I exit the program, and I have a memory leak I can't find. Here's the code

```
BoardP createNewBoard(int width, int high)
{
    BoardP board = (BoardP) malloc(sizeof(Board));

    if (board == NULL)
    {
        reportError(MEM_OUT);
        return NULL;
    }
    board->height = high;
    board->width = width;
    board->matrix = createNewMatrix(width,high);
    printf("%c",board->matrix[1][1]);
    if (board->matrix == NULL)
    {
        reportError(MEM_OUT);
        freeBoard(board);
    return NULL;
    }
return board;
}

static char** createNewMatrix(int width, int height){
    char** newMatrix = (char**) calloc(height,sizeof(char*));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        newMatrix[i] = (char*) calloc(width,sizeof(char)); //LINE 71
        if (newMatrix[i] == NULL)
        {
            int j;
            for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                free(newMatrix[j]);
            }
            free(newMatrix);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return newMatrix;
 }
```

It is driving me crazy. All I do is to create a pointer to Board struct (which holds to integers and a two dimensional pointer array) and I have a memory leak. Here's the message:

```
==10436== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10436==     in use at exit: 100 bytes in 10 blocks
==10436==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 2 frees, 196 bytes allocated
==10436== 
==10436== 100 bytes in 10 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==10436==    at 0x4C2380C: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==10436==    by 0x4008C6: createNewMatrix (Board.c:71)
==10436==    by 0x40081E: createNewBoard (Board.c:55)
==10436==    by 0x4007C6: createNewDefaultBoard (Board.c:37)
==10436==    by 0x400F0C: main (PlayBoard.c:11)
==10436== 
==10436== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10436==    definitely lost: 100 bytes in 10 blocks
==10436==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10436==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10436==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10436==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

It points me to line 71, which calls calloc for a line in the matrix. When the program exits it calls freeBoard:

```
void freeBoard(BoardP board)
{
    if (board != NULL)
    {
        if(board->matrix != NULL)
        {
            free(board->matrix);
        }
        free(board);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I have a memory leak? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to free the individual lines, before freeing `matrix`.

```
for (i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    free(board->matrix[i]);
}
```

Comment: Great! but here's a question: what I calloc could only allocate part of the lines in the matrix? Would I be able to go through the expected number of lines and free them all, or do I have to know how many lines were allocated?

Comment: Set all the lines to `NULL` from the beginning. If `calloc` fails, it also returns NULL. In C it's legal to `free(NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the Matrix you allocate memory for all elements but you don't deallocate them in the function `freeBoard()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the confusion, you clearly *don't* free any of the `height` arrays of size `width*sizeof(char)`. Going by the output, both `height` and `width` are 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your free `free(board->matrix)` needs to free the matrix just how you free it in the NULL check of `createNewMatrix`.

```
void freeBoard(BoardP board)
{
    if (board != NULL)
    {
        if(board->matrix != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < board->height; i++)
            {
                free(board->matrix[i]);
            }
            free(board->matrix);
        }
        free(board);
    }
}
```

It may be easier to create a `freeMatrix` function accepting a height, or create a matrix structure that maintains its own height and width.

Answer (score 0):

`board->matrix` is a pointer to a pointer, which you have allocated dynamically. First you have used `calloc` to allocate the first dimension and *for each index* you used `calloc` to allocate the other dimension. Therefore you have an array of pointers which points to blocks of memory, and you have to free each block, indicated by each index.

In your code, you simply free the first dimension, each location of which points to the different blocks. On the other hand these blocks in the 2nd dimension are not freed.

You should do something like this:

```
void freeBoard(BoardP board)
{
    int i;
    if (board != NULL)
    {
        if(board->matrix != NULL)
        {
            for (i=0; i<board->height; i++);
               free(board->matrix[i]);
        }
        free(board);
    }
}
```

I have tried thing [in this post](http://phoxis.org/2011/07/13/allocating-multidimentional-array-at-runtime-in-c/)

Comment: Hi, say calloc failed before it has reach 'board->height', I don't know how many lines were allocated. What happens if I try to free a line that wasn't allocated?

Comment: This would still result int a leak since it does not free `board->matrix`

Comment: if it was not allocated, then initialize all the pointers in the first dimension to NULL. If there is an allocation failure, then at the time of freeing, you can check if `board->matrix[i]` is NULL or not and then call `free`. And you can pass NULL pointers in `free`, if you pass NULL to `free` no operation will be performed.